# Content of cell in wrong position innerHTML JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that displays names, their ages and the age of their parent.
I have two lines in which there is the sum of the ages.
For the sum of the parents' age I would like it to be in the parent age column but it is under the age column.

```js
let names = ["X", "Y"];
let ages = [22, 10];
let parentAge = [56,30]

const newTable = document.createElement("table");
newTable.classList.add("custom-table"); 

newTable.innerHTML = "<thead><th>Name</th><th>Index</th><th>Age</th><th>Parent Age</th></thead>";

let index = [];
for (let j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
  index.push(j + 1);
}

let ageTotal = 0; 
let ageParentTotal = 0;

if (names.length == ages.length) {
  for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    let newRow = document.createElement("tr");

    const tdName = document.createElement("td");
    tdName.textContent = names[i];
    newRow.appendChild(tdName);

    let tdIndex = document.createElement("td");
    tdIndex.textContent = index[i];
    newRow.appendChild(tdIndex);

    const tdAge = document.createElement("td");
    tdAge.textContent = String(ages[i]);
    ageTotal += ages[i]; 
    newRow.appendChild(tdAge);
    
    const tdAgeParent = document.createElement("td");
    tdAgeParent.textContent = String(parentAge[i]);
    ageParentTotal += parentAge[i]
    newRow.appendChild(tdAgeParent);
    newTable.appendChild(newRow);
  }
}

const target = document.getElementById('target');
target.appendChild(newTable);

let tdSumText = document.createElement("td");
tdSumText.textContent = "Sum age:";
let newRow2 = document.createElement("tr");
newRow2.appendChild(tdSumText);
newRow2.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));

let tdSumAge = document.createElement("td");
tdSumAge.textContent = ageTotal;
newRow2.appendChild(tdSumAge);
newTable.appendChild(newRow2);

let tdSumParentText = document.createElement("td");
tdSumParentText.textContent = "Sum age Parent :";
let newRow3 = document.createElement("tr");
newRow3.appendChild(tdSumParentText);
newRow3.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));

let tdSumAgeParent = document.createElement("td");
tdSumAgeParent.textContent = ageParentTotal;
newRow3.appendChild(tdSumAgeParent);
newTable.appendChild(newRow3);
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

If someone can help me ? I'm not sure I understand what appendChild do and the position of element by using inner HTML

Comment: Call `newRow3.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));` again to add another `td` before the sum value.

Comment: Thanks it's working but is there a method such "beautiful" rather than add "td" ? I think if I add a lot of column I will have a lot of appendChild(document.createElement("td));

Comment: That depends on what you mean by 'beautiful' :) You could build the HTML of the table from a single `<template>` element and inject it once, then update the relevant fields if you prefer.

Comment: Another popular way is to store the content in a data structure, and then use a loop to populate the table.

Comment: You may also use a colspan attribute to wider your column `Sum age Parent` such as `tdSumAgeParent.setAttribute("colspan", "3")` which avoid you to use a lot of column. See: [Element td - colspan](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#colspan)